# what does my request does not inlclude if-non-match in header

Tags: jquery, http-headers, browser-cache, http-caching

I am using https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache NUGET package to manage caching for my ASP.NET WEB API.

The server side caching works well. However I don't see it working on my browser (client side).

On request I see that max-age and etag is being returned.

However I make further request I don't see etag being supplied with request header with if-non-match parameter. This is why I get response 200 (OK) back with response data. It should have parsed data from cache itself.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2781659/stackoverflow/Cache.jpg

Can anybody please advise?

Comment: I did further test and found that when I hit request like http://localhost/breeze/lfLookups if-none-match is being included on request and I get 304 response back with no data. That is what I expected. However I am using Breeze.js that actually makes this API calls and it constructs the URL as http://localhost/breeze/lfLookups?_=1381488654430 dynamically adding querystring parameter. AspNetWebApi-OutputCache has an option to exclude querystring parameter which I already set. Not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Is there any way in breeze.js so I can tell particular request not to include querystring parameter to my GET requests? ex. localhost/breeze/lfLookups?_=1381488654430 should just be localhost/breeze/lfLookups because context for this request is cached. If I can do that my issue should be resolved.

Comment: Are you sure the query string is the problem?  Can you check by copying and pasting a request into the browser URL?

Comment: URL is correct. The problem I see is that when an querystring parameters changes request header do not contain If-None-Match:"VALUE" part and that causes fresh data to load.

Comment: I see what is the issue. jQUery does handle the if-none-match header but it is available with current session only. I was trying to cache the json retrieved through jQuery ajax call. No solution has been found so far to me. Just an update.

Answer (score 1):

I just briefly looked at the Github project you referenced, and I wanted to throw in my $0.02, for whatever it's worth -

Breeze.js is responsible for taking care of client side caching for you.  The idea is to not have to worry about what the back-end is doing and simply make a logical decision on the client on whether to proceed and hit the server for data again.  If you don't need to refresh the data, then never hit the server, just return from Breeze's cache.

The project you are referencing seems to do both - server side and client-side caching.  The decision of caching on the server is one not to be taken lightly, but this project seems to handle it pretty well.

The problem is that you are trying to mix two libraries which, at best, conflict in the area of what their concerns are.  There may be a way to marry the two up, but at what cost?  Why would you need to cache on the server that which is already cached on the client?  Why cache on the client if you plan to cache the exact same data on the server?

The only reason I can think of is for paging of data (looking at a subset of the whole) and wanting to see the next data set without having to hit the server again.  In that case, your query to the server should not match the original anyway and therefore one would expect that you need to customize the two solutions to do what you are asking for.

In general that project seems to ignore queryString parameters, from what I can tell, to support JSONP so you should have no problem coming up with a custom solution, if you still think that is necessary.

Comment: I have a huge data that loads on initial single page application. This data can be modified on server but that is very rare. Server side caching is for fresh users requesting data and I do not want to hit the database. Client side cache will help use to load page much faster when I have it cached. Reason I do not want to use breeze caching mechanism is that I do want to invalidate cache HTTP level using eTags